# asp:repeater items not clearing when new dataSource set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I have a form in which I put one repeater control and bind it on pageLoad,it bind as expected.

I have a `dropDownList`,  when I select a value from it  I want to clear the repeater *dataSource* and rebind it in `dropDown_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler on codebehind.

I set the repeater datasource as null then rebind it with new datasource it wont reflect the changes, it display the first binded value.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsPostBack)
        return;

   //Populate the drop down
   PopulateLocationDropdown();

   if (Request.QueryString["locationID"] != null)
   {
       int locationID=Request.QueryString["locationID"];

       //Clear repeater 
       rpt_Displaytheater.DataSource = null;
       rpt_Displaytheater.DataBind();

       //Rebind repeater
       rpt_Displaytheater.DataSource = GetTheaterDataSet(locationID);
       rpt_Displaytheater.DataBind();
   }
}
```

When dropDown *selectionChanged* :

```
protected void ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int locationID=ddlLocation.SelectedValue.ToInt();

   //Clear repeater 
   rpt_Displaytheater.DataSource = null;
   rpt_Displaytheater.DataBind();

   //Rebind repeater
   rpt_Displaytheater.DataSource = GetTheaterDataSet(locationID);
   rpt_Displaytheater.DataBind();
}
```

### Edit

here is my dropdown :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" DataTextField="LocationName" DataValueField="Record_Id" runat="server" CssClass="textbox_230"
                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is my repeater :

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_Displaytheater" runat="server"
            OnItemCommand="rpt_Displaytheater_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="TheaterListing" style="background: #FFF;">
                    <div class="TheaterName">
                        <div class="Theaterhead">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTheaterID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Record_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnTheaterName" runat="server" Style="color: #000; font-weight: bold" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Theatre_Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="showlist">
                        <%-- show time repeater-Movies Tab --%>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_showtime" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <ul style="padding-left: 10px; margin: -18px 0 0 163px;">
                                    <li class="fl" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px;">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_showtime" CommandName="Showtime" runat="server" CssClass="txtstyle1"
                                            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Time_From") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        <%-- show time repeater-Movies Tab --%>
                        <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" style="color: #000;font-weight:bold" Text="10.00 AM"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br clear="all" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

My problem is when I reset repeater control's dataSource to new dataSource on dropDown selection changed but the changes is not reflected on the repeater it just show the first bounded values on page load whats wrong with my code

Comment: have you debug and test your code when the selected index changed it is actually call your method or not? and you need to set  `AutoPostBack="true"` for your ddlLocation control

Comment: there is nothing easier than putting a breakpoint to the ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged handler. you'll see whether the value of locationID is changing. there is nothing wrong with your code as far as i see. you don't have to set datasource to null. make sure autopostback of dropdown list is turned on.

Comment: @Damith ,yes I tested my code the Selection change event is fired when a location is selected on the dropdown I also set AutoPostBack to true

Comment: @rocky  the Selection change event is fired when a location is selected on the dropdown I also set AutoPostBack to true

Comment: is this your actual code? `int locationID=Request.QueryString["locationID"];` will not compile and what is `ToInt()`?

Comment: what about ddlLocation.SelectedValue in the event handler? does it change when you switch values in the DDL?

Comment: @Damith actually my code is bit long thats why abstracted it

Comment: @rocky yes my dropdown's DataValueField is set to RecordId of the collection when a selection is made on DDL locationID got new selected RecordId

Comment: Do you use update panels in the aspx markup?

Comment: @rocky, yes I do the repeater is inside a update panel

Comment: Then you need to call yourPanel.Update() or set the updatemode of the updatepanel to always.

Comment: @rocky , u save me man I put my updateMode to Conditional thanks again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63055/discussion-between-mussammil-and-rocky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refresh your asp:updatepanel.

This can be achieved by calling `yourPanel.Update()` or set the `UpdateMode` of your asp:updatepanel to `Always`.